# Setting origin of container to another container trouble (Swift 4.2)

Tags: ios, swift, user-interface, interface-builder

I'm trying to set the origin and width/height of one UIView (red) to a second UIView (blue).

I am calling UIView.frame.origin or size and for some reason the y origin doesn't work.

I've also tried with layout constraints (see it commented out below), but this is overriding my blue fully constrained view.

Then I have a button that animates the red view to the side so you can see the blue view underneath, but I can't get them to line up to start with.  Below is my code.  In interface builder, I have both UIViews set up as containers.  Blue is fully constrained with auto layout and red has no constraints.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController 
{

    @IBOutlet weak var blueContainer: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var redContainer: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var button: UIButton!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        print(redContainer.frame)

        redContainer.frame.origin.x = view.frame.width/2
        redContainer.frame.size.width = view.frame.width

        //try to line up y with origin and size
        redContainer.frame.origin.y = blueContainer.frame.origin.y
        redContainer.frame.size.height = blueContainer.frame.size.height

        //also tried by using constraints
        //redContainer.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: blueContainer.topAnchor).isActive = true
        //redContainer.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: blueContainer.heightAnchor).isActive = true

        print(redContainer.frame)
    }

    @IBAction func slideRed(_ sender: Any) {
        if redContainer.frame.origin.x == 0 {
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5) {
                self.redContainer.frame.origin.x = self.view.frame.width/2
            }
            button.setTitle("Come Back Red!", for: .normal)
        } else {
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5) {
                self.redContainer.frame.origin.x = 0
            }
            button.setTitle("Go Away Red!", for: .normal)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ViewDidLoad` does not guarantee the view has laid out its constraints. So when `blueContainer`'s `frame` and `size` is `zero`, you will not see any effect on `redContainer`. You should use `viewDidLayoutSubviews` to get the correct `frame` and `size` from `blueContainer`.

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()

    redContainer.frame.origin.x = view.frame.width/2
    redContainer.frame.size.width = view.frame.width

    //try to line up y with origin and size
    redContainer.frame.origin.y = blueContainer.frame.origin.y
    redContainer.frame.size.height = blueContainer.frame.size.height
}
```

Comment: I found out that my original code only worked if I updated my IB phone and my simulator phone to the same model. So your explanation makes so much sense.  Thanks for taking the time to explain and correct it, I was going crazy over this.